# Oracle ADF af:inputFile and af:commandButton give JS error on IE 9

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jspx

I have a a very simple jspx  with no backing bean:

```
<f:view>
    <af:document id="d1" title="Home">
      <af:form id="f1" usesUpload="true">
        <af:pageTemplate value="#{bindings.pageTemplateBinding.templateModel}" id="pt1">
          <f:facet name="content">
          <af:group>
          <af:inputFile label="" id="logoImageFile" />
            <af:commandButton text="Up" />
          </af:group>

          </f:facet>
        </af:pageTemplate>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
```

As soon as I click on the `commandButton` after selecting a file to upload, IE 9 throws a generic JS error. Other browsers [IE 8, FF, Chrome] are working fine. Even if I put `autosubmit=true` in `inputFile`, it throws an error unless I comment out the `commandButton`.

*Note: This is probably a component issue , however would like to know if any of you found a workaround/fix/patch. I am using Jdev 11.1.1.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set partialSubmit="true" for the button to avoid a full page reload

Comment: thanks the JS error has stopped. However I have a similar page, with the `commandButton` calling an action from the backing bean, and it refreshes the whole page in *only* IE9

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the incomplete support of IE 9 in Jdev 11.1.1.5. The issue does not replicate in Jdev 11.1.1.6 and higher (I tested only on 11.1.1.6)